Future perfect continuous without time expressions
Is it okay and correct to use future perfect continuous without duration?
1 I will have been working when she comes
2 I will have been swimming by May
Do you consider those example correct and think that future perfect continuous can be used without duration like "for 10 hours" or "2 days"?

Instead of asking whether random combinations of verb tenses are okay, why don't you describe in as many words as necessary the situation you're trying to express in a short sentence? Optionally with your guess as to how you think it should be expressed. There's no point in competent native speakers trying to invent bizarre contexts where your permutations might be credible, if those situations are never going to arise in the real world (and might be hard to describe even to other competent Anglophones, let alone people still trying to learn the basics of English verb forms! :)

@FumbleFingers  what do you mean? I asked a simple question if it possible to use future perfect continuous without time expressions like "for 2 days". I ask because I always see it with a time expression. Still I want to know if it is okay without that. There is no need to to explain anything more. I don't even know what more I could explain

It might be possible to think of a scenario where those sentences are meaningful, but normally the answer is no. Sentences like this are not natural-sounding without a mention of the duration of the activity.

@KateBunting perfect continuous infinitive is a part of future perfect continuous. My question is I could use that infinitve in different sentences for example "he pretends to have been working" and here it is okay without time expression. How can I know if I need a time expression or not with this perfect continuous infinitive?

I can only suggest that you read a lot of English and familiarise yourself with the way native speakers use it!

Yes, it's possible.  Absent context they sound strange but it's possible to create a reasonable context.

The national Olympic trials are this coming September.  A muscle tear   was   the worst thing that could happen to me at this juncture, but if it continues to heal as the doctors expect, I might stand a chance of making the team because I will have been swimming by May.

Though it would be more idiomatic to say ... because I will have been swimming again by May.
It's a future projection in regard to swimming as part of your regular routine.

My girlfriend is picking me up and we're going out to dinner to celebrate her new job. I will need to take a long hot shower because I will have been working when she arrives. She's not a big fan of pig farming and wishes I would find another line of work.


so my example number 1 is fine on its own too?

@Adam  What have I written that would make you think that your sentence is "fine on its own"?   I don't even know what "fine on its own" would mean in a language context. "grammatical"?   They need context.   I don't find "comes" to be as idiomatic as "arrives" for perfect tenses, BTW.

I might stand a chance of making the team because I will have been swimming by May sounds truly bizarre to me. If spoken before May, you'd obviously say ...because I will be swimming by May,  and after May you'd say ...because I was swimming by May. I think you're just pandering to the OP's misguided approach to learning how complex English verb forms work.

“… fingers crossed I will have started swimming in May” "… I will have begun competing/ training by May” Your examples work but not Adam nor Gregor's. They have (he has)  to understand that their short experimental sentences do not reflect how people speak or communicate in real life, despite the context you carefully crafted, by themselves these sentences don't sound  natural in the slightest.

@FumbleFingers Setting the pandering slandering aside, I'll address the "sounds truly bizarre to me". There is a telescoping of three times: the present, the distant future of trying out for the Olympic team, and the not-so-distant future  when he will have healed sufficiently to recommence training for the trials. If all goes well with the healing process, he will stand a chace of making the team come trials because he will have been swimming by May.  Normally the future perfect establishes a future retrospective vantage point, so that he'd say "because I will have ...

been training since May". But the  looking forward to recommencing training causes him to say by May.
